# Global Statemachine Handler in Godot

Tags: godot

I'm trying to get this finite state machine to work, but it doesn't have anything to do with the run state of the player here is the code:

State.gd

````rust
    extends KinematicBody2D
    class_name State
    
    var state_machine = null
    
    var player_velocity = Vector2()
    var player_speed = 200
    var player_energy = 50
    
    enum playerStates{IDLE, WALK, RUN, USE, SHOOT}
    enum ItemStates{ITEM_ON_GROUND, IS_EQUIPED}
    enum Inventory{SELECTED, NOTSELECTED}
    
    var parent = get_parent()
    
    func _ready():
        if Global.player_isIdle == State.state_machine == playerStates.IDLE:
            pass
        if Global.player_isWalking == State.state_machine == playerStates.WALK:
            State.player_speed = Global.player_speed
            State.player_speed = 200
        if Global.player_isRunning == State.state_machine == playerStates.RUN:
            State.player_speed = Global.player_speed
            State.player_speed = 300
        else:
            Global.player_isWalking == State.state_machine == playerStates.WALK
                
    func handle_input(_event: InputEvent):
        if Global.player_velocity != Global.player_velocity.ZERO:
            if Global.player_isWalking == State.state_machine == playerStates.WALK:
                pass
            if Global.player_isRunning == State.state_machine == playerStates.RUN:
                if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
                    print("RUN")
            Global.player_velocity = Global.player_velocity.normalized() * player_speed
            Global.player_velocity = move_and_slide(Global.player_velocity)
            
    func _physics_process(_delta):
        Global.player_velocity = parent.move_and_slide(Global.player_velocity)
    ```

Player.gd
```rust

    onready var velocity = Global.player_velocity
    ...
    func get_input():
        velocity = Vector2()
        #speed = Global.player_speed
        
        if Input.is_action_pressed("sprint"):
            Global.player_isRunning = true 
            #speed = 300
        else:
            #speed = 200
            pass
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move-right"):
            Global.player_direction = "0"
            velocity.x += 1
            if $Footsteps.playing == false:
                $Footsteps.play()
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move-left"):
            Global.player_direction = "1"
            velocity.x -= 1
            if $Footsteps.playing == false:
                $Footsteps.play()
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move-down"):
            Global.player_direction = "2"
            velocity.y += 1
            if $Footsteps.playing == false:
                $Footsteps.play()
        if Input.is_action_pressed("move-up"):
            Global.player_direction = "3"
            velocity.y -= 1
            if $Footsteps.playing == false:
                $Footsteps.play()
        
        velocity = velocity.normalized() * speed
        velocity = move_and_slide(velocity)
    ```
Global.gd
```rust

    extends Node2D
    
    var player_initial_map_position = Vector2(50,50)
    var player_direction = ["LEFT","RIGHT","UP","DOWN"]
    var player_velocity = Vector2()
    var player_speed
    
    var player_isIdle : bool
    var player_isWalking : bool
    var player_isRunning : bool
    var player_isUsing : bool
    var player_isShooting : bool
    
    var player_pickedUpItem : bool
    var player_DropItem : bool
    
    var pressed_button
    
    var hasM4a1 : bool
    var hasMiningDrill : bool
````

if anyone can figure out how i can use the state machine please respond to me with some methods on how i can get the state machine to work and also i have a detailed software architecture functional model [image]

Answer (score 1):

*I'm having trouble parsing your diagram. To spare you the rant, I've decided to ignore it.*

---

Before getting into the state machine, I want to encourage using [types](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/static_typing.html).

I can see some variables changing type, for example, you declare this array:

```
var player_direction = ["LEFT","RIGHT","UP","DOWN"]
```

But - apparently - override it with a `String`:

```
Global.player_direction = "0"
```

This sort of thing does not give me confidence on the correctness of the code as a whole.

---

**Property ant match**

We start with an `enum`, such as the one you have:

```
enum playerStates{IDLE, WALK, RUN, USE, SHOOT}
```

Then we are going to have a property of that type:

```
var state:playerStates
```

Then we can match that property to the values of the `enum` wherever you need:

```
match state:
   playerStates.IDLE:
       pass # code here
   playerStates.WALK:
       pass # code here
   playerStates.RUN:
       pass # code here
   playerStates.USE:
       pass # code here
   playerStates.SHOOT:
       pass # code here
```

That is cleaner than using `if` statements. And it is a good approach if you know all the states before hand. However, notice that if you modify `enum`, you need to consider every place where you `match` that you might need to update.

About the state transitions, they are simply setting the variable. For example:

```
state = playerStates.RUN
```

We can improve upon that by having a dedicated method to set the state. And only ever write the state there. *Which takes a little dicipline.* For example:

```
func set_state(new_value:playerStates) -> void:
    state = new_value
```

And there you can handle state transitions with a `match`:

```
func set_state(new_value:playerStates) -> void:
    if state == new_value:
        return

    match new_value:
        playerStates.IDLE:
            pass # code here
        playerStates.WALK:
            pass # code here
        playerStates.RUN:
            pass # code here
        playerStates.USE:
            pass # code here
        playerStates.SHOOT:
            pass # code here

    state = new_value
```

Furthermore you could use [`setget`](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/scripting/gdscript/gdscript_basics.html#setters-getters). However, be aware that from the same class a setter would not run unless you use `self` to access it. *Which also takes a little dicipline.*

We can improve over that by using a function for each state:

```
func set_state(new_value:playerStates) -> void:
    if state == new_value:
        return

    var method_name := "on_" + playerStates.keys()[new_value]
    if has_method(method_name):
        call_deferred(method_name)

    state = new_value

func on_IDLE() -> void:
    pass # code here

func on_WALK() -> void:
    pass # code here

func on_RUN() -> void:
    pass # code here

func on_USE() -> void:
    pass # code here

func on_SHOOT() -> void:
    pass # code here
```

This takes a little explanation.

First, when you declare an `enum`, Godot creates a dictionary with its values. So we can use it to query the name of a value like this `EnumName.keys()[value]` or we can query the value of a name like this `EnumName[value]`.

Second, we can check for a method name with `has_method`. *Which you would not have to do if you make sure to declare them. But I have here for completeness.*  And we can call a method by name using `call` or `call_deferred`. *In my experience `call_deferred` is what you want. It will avoid performance issues with state transitions changing the state. A drawback is that you lose track of the old state, because for the time the method is called, the state already changed.*

---

**Nodes**

So far the issues are:

- You need discipline to keep changes of state in a single place.
- It takes extra consideration and effort to change the possible states.

We can address the first one by having a dedicated State Machine object that our code interacts with. So that all the checks and manipulations of the state has to go through it.

To address the second part, we can make classes instead of using an `enum`. In fact, in Godot, I would suggest to make them `Node`s.

This leads to this organization in the scene tree:

```
StateMachine
├ IdleState
├ WalkState
├ RunState
├ UseState
└ ShootState
```

The `StateMachine` would have a script, which will expose a property that you can use to set the state. Now, we probably don't want to pass a `Node`, so I'll make it take a `String`:

```
extends Node

var state:String setget set_state
var state_node:Node setget no_set

func set_state(new_state:String) -> void:
    var candidate_node := get_node_or_null(new_state + "State")
    if not is_instance_valid(candidate_node):
        return

    if state_node == candidate_node:
        return

    if candidate_node.get_parent() != self:
        return

    state = new_state
    state_node = candidate_node


func no_set(_new_value) -> void:
    push_error("Do not set the state_node directly")
```

Let us break this down:

- We are making a couple properties with `setget`. So when we try to set them from another script, it results in executing the given methods (`set_state` and `no_set`).
- The method `set_state` will try to get a child node with a name derived from the given `String`.

  - We check `is_instance_valid` in case we didn't get a valid `Node` (e.g. we got `null`).
  - We check if the `Node` we got is the same we had, in which case we do nothing.
  - And we check if the `Node` we got is a child of the `StateMachine`. *This a defensive programming check.*
  - Finally, if everything is OK, we change the state.
- The method `no_set`, intentionally does nothing except pushing an error. It is there to remind you to not set the `Node` directly - and to an extend, prevent it.

Now each of the states can have their own methods and properties. *In fact, using nodes brings the opportunity of using `export var` to make the states easily configurable from the editor.*

Let us say, for example, that you need to handle input differently depending on the state, you can have this in your player:

```
StateMachine.state_node.handle_input()
```

Which would result in calling an `handle_input` on the current state `Node`. Then each of the state `Node`s can define that method:

```
func handle_input() -> void:
    pass # code here
```

**We need to decide how the states are going to access the player.** *I'll leave that for the end.*

Ah, right, the state transitions. Previously we had a `match` in `set_state` an we were calling methods based on the name. We approach that too. For example, we can give a `current` property to all state `Node`s:

```
var current:bool = false
```

Then we will set it form `set_state`

```
func set_state(new_state:String) -> void:
    var candidate_node := get_node_or_null(new_state + "State")
    if not is_instance_valid(candidate_node):
        return

    if state_node == candidate_node:
        return

    if candidate_node.get_parent() != self:
        return

    if is_instance_valid(state_node) and "current" in state_node:
        state_node.current = false

    state = new_state
    state_node = candidate_node

    if "current" in state_node:
        state_node.current = true
```

Notice here that I'm using `in` to check if the `Node` has a particular property. *Again, this is a defensive programming check. You could avoid that if you make sure they all have it.*

Furthermore, we can use `setget` on `current` to handle the state transitions:

```
var current:bool = false setget set_current

func set_current(new_value:bool) -> void:
    pass # code here
```

So we have no `match` and no `if` statements anywhere at all.

---

**States with behavior**

We have been putting methods in the states, so they do have behavior. And they are `Node`s in the scene tree. We can push that further, and use `_process` or `_physics_process` in them. For that I'd suggest enabling and disabling them with the `current` variable:

```
var current:bool = false setget set_current

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    pass

func set_current(new_value:bool) -> void:
    set_physics_process(new_value)
    pass # code here
```

---

**Class inheritance**

I want to mention that we can make a base class for the state `Node`s. And there we can put the common code for all the sates, something like this:

```
class_name StateNodeBase extends Node

var current:bool = false setget set_current

func _physics_process(delta:float) -> void:
    pass

func set_current(new_value:bool) -> void:
    set_physics_process(new_value)
    on_set_current(new_value)

func on_set_current(new_value:bool) -> void:
    pass

func handle_input() -> void:
    pass # NO code here
```

And then the state `Node` extend that, replacing only the methods they need.

*Notice I have split `set_current` into `set_current` and `on_set_current`, where `on_set_current` is the part intended to be replaced.*

For example:

```
extends StateNodeBase

func on_set_current(new_value:bool) -> void:
    pass # code here

func handle_input() -> void:
    pass # code here
```

---

**Passing the player**

There are multiple approaches to pass a reference to the player to the states. And I would rather not enumerate them.

In fact, I have a philosophical question for you: Are these states or behaviors? Since we have been putting methods in the states, they do have behavior. If they ought to be behaviors, perhaps they should not have internal state. Which would allow you to reuse them. *For example, if you have enemies with an state machine created as described here. Each of them would have a copy of the state machine. But what if you could only have one copy and reuse it?*

Anyway, to keep it simple, the solution I'll put forth is to use `owner`. This requires making the player the root of its own scene, like this:

```
Player
├ OtherStuff
└ StateMachine
  ├ IdleState
  ├ WalkState
  ├ RunState
  ├ UseState
  └ ShootState
```

If the `Player` is the root of the scene. Then `owner` of the other nodes will refer to it.

Answer (score 0):

This is from [GDQuest](https://www.gdquest.com/tutorial/godot/design-patterns/finite-state-machine/).
Hopefully, it will help you.
It worked for me perfectly.
You can make many state machines,
one for player movement, one for attacking state and many more.

Comment: var method_name := "on_" + playerStates.keys()[new_value]

not sure what to put on this line as it gets an error:
error(32,1): Invalid index type (playerStates) for base "Array"

as for the context of what you have written i am up to Nodes, could you explain that section a bit more please